# How can I reference a div's defined value using jquery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reference a div with a predetermined value I made using jquery, and can't seem to find the appropriate method.

I've tried using the .find() and .attr() methods to no avail. I have a feeling this has to do with scope but I'm at a loss.

I am trying to make changes to the neighboring divs (.cube) based on their row and col value. my alert script keeps returning an undefined result.

```js
 <div class="cube" id="1" row="1" col="1"></div>
<div class="cube" id="2" row="1" col="2"></div>
<div class="cube" id="3" row="1" col="3"></div>
<div class="cube" id="4" row="1" col="4"></div>

$(".cube").each(function() {
  var adjacentrowplus = +$(this).attr('row') + 1;
  var adjacentcolplus = +$(this).attr('col') + 1;
  var adjacentrowminus = +$(this).attr('row') - 1;
  var adjacentcolminus = +$(this).attr('col') - 1;
  if ($(".cube").attr("row") == adjacentrowplus) {
    console.log("the div equals the row");
  } else {
    console.log("the div doesnt equal the row");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cube" id="1" row="1" col="1"></div>
<div class="cube" id="2" row="1" col="2"></div>
<div class="cube" id="3" row="1" col="3"></div>
<div class="cube" id="4" row="1" col="4"></div>
```

Comment: my alert script keeps returning an undefined result. undefined result of unexpected result?

Comment: Side note, you should be using `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is just a bit off. If you look at your `if` statement as pseudo code we can see it will never return `true`:

First iteration only:

```
if 1 == 1 + 1 then print "the div equals the row"
```

As you can see, adding one to the value of `row`, then checking that against the value of `row` doesn't make sense.

Instead, check the incremented `row` value against the `id` attribute.

In addition, you were checking against `$(".cube").attr("row")` which will always check only the first one. If that makes sense, I'll change my answer to reflect that. But, I assumed you wanted to check the currently iterating `.cube`.

**EDIT** To accommodate the updated goal: *identify the neighboring elements*

This becomes a much easier problem to solve then. Given the structure provided in the question below you will find a jQuery version and straight JavaScript solution:

```js
let id = 2;

function findNeighborsJQ(id) {
  console.log('With jQuery:');
  console.log('Prev cube: ', $('#'+id).prev('div.cube').attr('id'));
  console.log('Next cube: ', $('#'+id).next('div.cube').attr('id'));
}

function findNeighbors(id) {
  console.log('Without jQuery:');
  console.log('Prev cube: ', document.getElementById(id).previousElementSibling.id);
  console.log('Next cube: ', document.getElementById(id).nextElementSibling.id);
}

console.log('Given and id of "'+id+'"...');
findNeighborsJQ(id);
findNeighbors(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cube" id="1" row="1" col="1"></div>
<div class="cube" id="2" row="1" col="2"></div>
<div class="cube" id="3" row="1" col="3"></div>
<div class="cube" id="4" row="1" col="4"></div>
```

Comment: Not quite Randy, I am not trying to get the currently itterated cube but the surrounding cubes that have the correct row and col div attributes

Comment: I'm here to help...So, suffice it to say that `$(".cube").attr("row")` doesn't do anything with "surrounding cubes" - it selects _the first_ cube. Your HTML doesn't have any elements that "surround" others, so I take it to mean "adjacent" cubes? Finally, I have no way of knowing what "_correct row and div attributes_" is supposed to mean. Can edit your question to include pseudo code that demonstrates exactly what you just told me in your comment?

Comment: Done. appologies, that was supposed to have been included in my original question

Comment: Thanks Randy, but not quite the goal I am after. If I am not mistaken, what you proposed only allows me to get the next and previous ids based on an iteration of ids, unfortunately I need to get the id of the div based ONLY on the row and col attributes in the divs, not their ids. without a lengthy explanation, i have a grid layout of divs, and what you proposed only gets me the X axis of this grid, I need the X and Y, hense the row and col attributes being involved at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. You've asked a question with a set of four divs. You state you want to _identify the neighboring elements_, I've provided two solutions based upon those four divs - and for both you've changed the scenario. NOW, it is a grid - you've never mentioned a grid until after all of this. What's next, a cube? Can't anticipate what you don't tell us. Please, please edit your question with ALL the details. You've wasted my time.

Comment: Appologies if this has wasted any time for you Randy. Ive simplified my question for the scope of my problem, hense me not explaining this grid, I am trying not to over complicate the question. I had thought I made it rather clear I am simply trying to derive the id from the row and col values of these divs, not their ids. For the scope of this question, I don't feel noting that these divs are layed out in a grid is relevant to the problem.

Comment: OK, let's go down THAT rabbit hole. The only thing you need to change in my current solution to "get the row and col values" is to change `.id` to `.row` or `.col`. Nothing else changes. You'll have those values for the neighboring elements. Now tell me how that's wrong in some way because, what? It doesn't get the row and col values?